# Python and tkinter window combine

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python sudoku game which is written by **pygame** and I have a start window(like the ones you see at the start of games) which is written with Tkinter. I want to combine them; first, the Tkinter window comes, and the user clicks on the play, then the **pygame** window shows up. How can I do so? When I try with this code :

```
`from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import webbrowser



fen = Tk()
fen.geometry("700x600")
fen.resizable(height=False, width=False)
fen.iconbitmap('logo.png')
fen.title("Sudoku Game")
fen.configure(bg="#74D0F1")


#zone de texte : titre "Sudoku Game"
label2 = Label(fen, text="Sudoku Game", bg='#74D0F1', fg='black', font=("Arial", 40))
label2.place(x=215, y=160)


#zone de texte : Solver Available !
label1 = Label(fen, text="Solver Available !", bg='#74D0F1', fg='black', font=("Arial", 15))
label1.place(x=500, y=450)


#bouton play
def ouvrir_grille():
    exec(open("/Users/nikitakarpachev/Desktop/Sudoku.py/test12.py").read())
#link to the file with the code for the sudoku game 
 
button = Button(fen, text="PLAY",command=ouvrir_grille, font=("Arial", 15), width=8, height=3)

button.place(x=285, y=280)

#bouton "how to play"
img = PhotoImage(file='icons8-info-100.png')

rules = Button(fen, image=img,command=lambda: webbrowser.open("https://sudoku.com/how-to-play/sudoku-rules-for-complete-beginners/"),
highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, border=0, relief="flat")
rules.place(x=500, y=50)



fen.mainloop()
```

I get the pygame window opening but it's full black, like just a black window opening.
Can someone help?

I tried the code posted above and expected to get my pygame window opening correctly with the sudoku grid and all that stuff but I got just a black window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should not use pygame and tkinter together. Even if you find a working way, it's not guaranteed to work when an update comes along. But you can make a menu with pygame alone.